# LINQ: Compare List A and B, if in B, select item in A

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of tags (List A), and a list of tags matched to topics (List B). I want to parse all items in List B and if it's there, have it select the item in List A. I've tried to do a two line and one line statement to do this, but I run into the same problem no matter what I try. Here's my one line attempt of code:

```
var tags = db.Tags.Where(x=>x.TagID == db.TagLink.Where(y => y.TopicID == incomingTopicID)).ToList();
```

List A and B have a common column of Tag ID.

Any suggestions?

### Update

The structure of db.TagLink are these columns: TagLinkID(Key), TopicID, TagID.

The structure of db.Tags are these columns: TagID, TagName, IsTagScored.

Comment: How do List A and List B relate to your code?  What is `tempData`?  What is `i`?  What is the problem you run into?

Comment: It would really help if you'd provide a full example. It sounds like you just need a join, but it's hard to tell with this fairly vague description.

Comment: @CharlesMager it's just an instance of an incoming TopicID number. I will re-write the example.

Comment: As an aside, this looks like it might be EF.  If it is, I'd expect you to have a `Tag` navigation property on  `TagLink` (in addition to `TagId`), which makes this a very trivial query.  I think, as @JonSkeet suggests, you need to add more context.

Comment: Your example code doesn't have an `A`. Or a `B`. Or any lists.

Comment: Rather than just "the structure of", please provide a short but complete example demonstrating the problem. It's *always* easier to help people if we can see a complete example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways you could go about it. Here's one approach:

```
var tags = db.Tags
    .Where(x=>db.TagLink
        .Any(y => y.TagId == x.TagId && y.TopicID == incomingTopicID))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Join`, like this:

```
var tags = db.TagLink.Where(x => x.TopicID == incomingTopicID)
                     .Join(db.Tag, x => x.TagId, y => y.TagId, (x, y) => y)
                     .ToList();
```